# Android play a video url in external player

Tags: android, video-streaming

I want to to stream my video to an external player on my phone. I have double twist installed and I want that that to open a my video URL. How can I do this?

Comment: What you need to do is contact the author of Double Twist and ask them to add an Intent to handle URLs.

Answer (score 11):

It is a good practice to let user of your app to select the Video player he likes to play your Video

Create a Intent Chooser which lets your user choose a Video player of his choice and play the file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://ur URL"), "video/*");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I believe this would only answer the question if the person posting it were the developer of the app.  In this case I believe they're the user.

Comment: @mikebabcock Yes that is true, but a good developer doesn't stick to one option to complete his task, he will think otherwise, what if the user doesn't have that one app installed which he supports?

Comment: I am the developer. I am looking to allow the end user to play a video in the external player.

Comment: ok, doesn't my answer help, if it doesn't then can you please elaborate more on what you want.

Comment: opening extrnal video player but, Can't play this video

Comment: maybe your device doesn't have the appropriate video codec, try with another device or install media codecs in your device.

Comment: Thanks. How to enable "default" option in the Chooser menu?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to fire my QRcode scanner,
I guess you could find out package and activity name for doubleTwist(I don't have this player handy, else I would have found out). Use something like this below -

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");  
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");    
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I am not sure where will you click your Url from, from any webview or from native component, because depending on them, event handling the click would change.